# Array query, Index out of bounds

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm a total newbie and know I'm probably going about this the complete wrong way. I'm trying to populate a spinner wheel with the dates of all the Mondays in a month when the user selects a given month and year. To do this I'm using two loops, the first to count how many in the month, either 4 or 5, and the second to fill an array of length x set by the first loop! This is working at first glance but when I move the month forward by 4 months to October I get the following error

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Some help would be greatly appreciated as i presume there is a better way. My code is as follows..........

```
int year1 = year.getCurrentItem();
    int month1 = month.getCurrentItem();
    int count = 0;

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year1, month1, 1);

    do { 
        int day1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (day1 == Calendar.MONDAY) {
            count++;
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }  while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month1);

    int count2 = 0;

    recordArray = new String[count];

    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(year1, month1, 1);

    do {   
        int day1 = cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (day1 == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            recordArray[count2] = Integer.toString(cal2.get((Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))-1);
            count2++;
        }
        cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }  while (cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month1);
```

Comment: "*I get the following error*" -- at which line?

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops? You could do all the work in one loop

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @aioobe but @jampag spotted my error there! See below......

Comment: I'm new at this programming malarke and knew it was probably an awkward way of doing it and I didn't know about the ArrayList, but I do now, thanks to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second `do{}while()` change `if (day1 == Calendar.SUNDAY)` to `if (day1 == Calendar.MONDAY)`

But I think would be better to use something like `ArrayList` and one do-while cycle except two.

```
...
ArrayList<String> recordArray = new ArrayList<String>();
do { 
        int day1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (day1 == Calendar.MONDAY) {
            recordArray.add(Integer.toString(cal2.get((Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))-1));
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}  while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month1);
...
```

Comment: Of course, how silly of me! I have to learn how to spot these mistakes more efficiently! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an array out of bounds exception because sometimes a month has 4 Mondays and 5 Sundays.

recordArray is the size of the number of mondays (4), and
youre accessing recordArray[count2], which can be recordArray[5] (out of bounds)

Based on your description, it sounds like you didn't mean to check sundays... so the answer is to change that Sunday to Monday

Comment: Cheers Matt for your reply, sorted there now!